# Processes are not executing in the order I execute them, and device is not responding to Tap event on Windows Phone. How to resolve?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to do 3 things in this order:

1. Start `MediaPlayer` playing some audio tracks
2. Show a `MessageBox` while audio is playing (user can close this at any time)
3. Tap the screen to stop the media player. (after the messagebox is closed)

E.g.:

```
private void DoTheseThings()
{
    // start playing audio first
    PlaySongs();

    // then show message box
    MessageBox.Show("The audio has started"); 
}

private void PlaySongs()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        foreach (var song in songs)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(delay);

            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        }
    });
}

// stop playing audio when the screen is tapped
private override void OnTap(System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
    });

}
```

The problem is the `MessageBox` pops up before the audio starts, and nothing plays until I click OK on the `MessageBox`. The audio should start before the `MessageBox`!

And then when I tap the screen nothing happens until after all the audio is finished playing. If I tap the screen 3 times `OnTap` fires 3 times when the audio is all done, but at this point it's way to late.

**What do I need to do to get these things to happen in the correct order, and have the `OnTap` event respond and stop the MediaPlayer when I need it to?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you start the song using dispatcher and not directly - the anonymous method is scheduled to run on UI thread as soon as there is nothing else to do, but before that the MessageBox is shown. The MessageBox is also modal, so the scheduled start of the song won't start until you close the MessageBox window.
**Try to add the MessageBox into the anonymous method** after the song start. Also why do you need to use the dispatcher anyway for starting/stoppping songs?